# TO display record in one row

Tags: informix

I have this sql statement as to retrieve one row only, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
select pav_employee,pav_name,pas_paycode,
pas_amount,pav_paynettamt 
from m_advhdr,m_payshthdr,m_payshtline
where pav_payno='161'
and pav_employee IS NOT NULL
and pah_employee=pav_employee
and pas_magic=pah_magic
and pav_payno=pah_payno
```

The query returns the following result:

```
K00018|AIDEN|B100|5890.51|6573.31|
K00018|AIDEN|D017|1.0|6573.31|
K00018|AIDEN|D400|2.0|6573.31|
```

but I want it to display only in one line `K00018|AIDEN|B100|5890.51|D017|1.0|D400|2.0|6573.31|`

How to change the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. For an SQL question like this, we need an MCVE ([MCVE]). The MCVE needs to include at least outline table schemas (for example, are the `pav_*` columns from `m_advhdr`, the `pas_*` columns from `m_payshtline`, and the `pah_*` columns from `m_payshthdr`? Ideally, you'd be using the modern JOIN notation rather than the comma-list of tables in the FROM clause with the joins in the WHERE clause. Also, you'd show enough rows of data from the tables to give the answer you show. An MCVE stops us having to guess!

Comment: Would there ever be more than three `pas_paycode` and `pas_amount` rows in the answer?

Comment: pav* is a column name from  m_advhdr table
pah* column name is for m_payshthdr  and pas* column name is for m_payshtline table.Yes,the pas_paycode and pas_amount that I want to select is for one employee only.This would be the sample,The record I want to get is the list of  salary for the month for all employees.

Comment: Please edit the information into the question.  Will each employee always have three records, or could there be more (how many more) or less?  What do you want returned if there are fewer records?  How do you want to handle it if there are more records?  How should the pairs of fields be ordered in the result?